# Mask_RCNN: How to save trained model and convert it to tflite

Tags: tensorflow, keras, file-conversion, tensorflow-lite

I followed the tutorial at 
https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-train-an-object-detection-model-with-keras/

After successful training I got 5 **.h5** files:

```
mask_rcnn_kangaroo_cfg_0001.h5
mask_rcnn_kangaroo_cfg_0002.h5
mask_rcnn_kangaroo_cfg_0003.h5
mask_rcnn_kangaroo_cfg_0004.h5
mask_rcnn_kangaroo_cfg_0005.h5
```

I am a newbie to this, so my understanding may be wrong:

How can I convert these **.h5** files to **.pb** files or better to **.tflite** files, so I can use them in an Android Object Detection app?

Comment: If any error persists in the conversion of .h5 to TFLite, I would insist you use TF Object Detection API.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert these .h5 to .pb, you can directly convert keras .h5 files to tflite. Here is the official documentation on [how to](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api#converting_a_keras_model_).

Make sure to have the model with layers supported by TFLite, as mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_compatibility).

Once you have the .tflite model you can run an interpreter on Android.

Comment: How do I know if all layers in a  Mask_RCNN trained model are supported by TFLite?

Comment: You need to go through the layers defined in Mask_RCNN and check them if they are supported by TFLite operation.

Comment: when converting keras model to tflite ::OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: model.hdh5/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb} @RishabhSahrawat

Comment: @HarshGupta it means either there is not file present at the location you are specifying or you are giving the wrong name. Just a quick check, it is `hdf5` type not `hdh5` so maybe this is the problem.

Comment: @RishabhSahrawat yeah I use wrong extension , but i tried with .h5 extension OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: model.h5/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}

Comment: Can you share the code you are using for calling the file?